# Form based and Certificate based authentication in Spring Framework / Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, x509, digital-certificate

is it possible in spring framework to have 2 login implementation at the same time for the login page? Form login and Certificate based login (x509). I've tried either one of these method but combining them at the same time, it is hard for me to do it. Any idea how to enable these two methods? Any book or site reference that I can refer to regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, by making the SSL client-auth optional.

[Here on Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security#Mutual) is a good tutorial on enabling SSL client authentication with X.509 certificates, with forced client-auth (not good for your case, with login form fallback)

Follow that tutorial and pay attention in the *application.properties* file to make the client-auth **want** instead of **need**. This will make the client-server SSL handshake attempt to ask for a certificate.

```
server.ssl.client-auth=want
```

- If the browser does not provide a certificate (does not have any configured or the user clicks on cancel when prompted to select a certificate from a list), the SSL handshake will be done without the client certificate, and the user will have to login with username+password
- If the user chooses a certificate, the SSL handshake is done with the client certificate. The server then verifies the given certificate in the trust-store. If the certificate is valid, the SSL handshake is successfully established. Otherwise, the connection is refused by the server.

Pay attention that

- only the authentication is done with the x.509 certificate. For authorization, you must provide the [X509Configurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/X509Configurer.html) an [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) implementation, to retrieve the [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) for the user that just authenticated via x.509
- thus, if you have a database of users with their assigned roles, even if the certificate is in the trust-store, the user might not be in the user database, so you will have to treat this possibility in your application logic. I.e. when the SSL connection is mutual, but the user is not present in the user database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. All you need is to declare x509 support in your http config:

```
<http ...>
    ...
    <x509 ... />
    ....
</http>
```

and configure SSL in Tomcat.

See [this entry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/x509.html) and [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78535-Combine-X509-and-Form-based-login&s=e077b42fd45ae3a3177a01c90339893c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I am having is on my login page, I have two login authentication. Form based and Certificate authentication. I set the clientAuth parameter in tomcat's server.xml to "want" and when I visit the login page, it asks me to select a certificate. I wanted to only select a certificate once I click on the certificate authentication button =). Would that be possible? How? =)

Comment: Which version of Tomcat do you use? Can you try clientAuth="optional"?

Comment: Hi Maksym Demidas. I'm using Tomcat 6.0.36. I didn't see the "optional" as the value in tomcat documentation. Did  it works for you setting to "optional" and prompts the user to select certificate for a selected protected pages? I don't want the browser asks me to select a certificate for the login page =). Thanks

Comment: @MaksymDemidas: the reference link is broken, please update to current - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/x509.html